# Trying to add a calculated distance to Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, query-builder, eloquent

I am trying to add a distance calculated inside a Model::get() method. The distance should be marked as "distance", while now it returns nothing (no added select).

Here is my Eloquent Query : 
`

```
Candidate::whereHas('positions', function($query) use ($data) {
           $query->where('positions.id', $data['position']);
        })
        ->whereHas('user', function($query) use ($data) {
           $query->where('status', '=', 1);
           if($data['lat'] !== null and $data['lng'] !== null){
           $query->whereHas('address', function($query) use ($data) {
           $sqlDistance = DB::raw('( 111.045 * acos( cos( radians(' . $data['lat'] . ') ) * cos( radians( addresses.latitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( addresses.longitude ) - radians(' . $data['lng']  . ') ) 
+ sin( radians(' . $data['lat']  . ') ) * sin( radians( addresses.latitude ) ) ) )');
           $query->selectRaw("{$sqlDistance} AS distance");
          });
         }
         })->with('user.address','user','user.media')
         ->get();
```

`

Here is what I get :

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is a mix between Eloquent and Query Builder :

`

```
Candidate::select('candidates.*')
            ->whereHas('positions', function ($query) use ($data) {
                $query->where('positions.id', $data['position']);
            })
            ->whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($data) {
                $query->where('status', '=', 1);
                $query->whereHas('address', function ($query) use ($data) {
                    if($data['country'] !== null){
                        $query->where('country', '=', $data['country']);
                    }
                });
            })
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'candidates.user_id')
            ->with('user.address', 'user', 'user.media','reviews')
            ->leftJoin('addresses', 'addresses.id', 'users.address_id')
            ->addSelect(DB::raw("{$sqlDistance} AS distance") )
            ->get();
```

`

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to find the business distance from user's current location. 
`$request->latitude` & `$request->longitude` is user's current location which will be pass in request and I have already stored business's location in database column named `latitude` & `longitude`. `selectSub()` is used to add column in data records. It will contain two arguments first it will be function or column name and the second one will be a new column name.

```
Business::with(['user','category'])
    ->select('*')
    ->selectSub('(111.111 *
        DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(latitude))
            * COS(RADIANS('.$request->latitude.'))
            * COS(RADIANS(longitude - '.$request->longitude.'))
            + SIN(RADIANS(latitude))
            * SIN(RADIANS('.$request->latitude.'))))))','distance_in_km')
    ->orderBy('distance_in_km','ASC')
    ->take($limit)
    ->skip($offset)->get();
```

Here is my working code in laravel

Comment: please, add necessary explanation

Comment: done please review it Let me know if anything more. Thanks (Y)